# Rails and Paperclip, default_url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip for uploading profile pictures. When someone does not upload an image I want a default image to be assigned to the user instead.

I'm using this line of code:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
  styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
  default_url: "assets/images/:style/male.jpg"
```

But my browser inspector gives me this error:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/images/original/male.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried writing:

```
default_url: "assets/images/:style/male.jpg"
default_url: "images/:style/male.jpg"
default_url: ":style/male.jpg"
default_url: "male.jpg"
default_url: "assets/images/male.jpg"
```

The image lies in the following places:

```
/assets/images/male.jpg 
/assets/images/medium/male.jpg 
/assets/images/thumb/male.jpg 
/assets/images/original/male.jpg
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ommit the `/images/` instead do this `/assets/male.jpg` or `/assets/original/male.jpg`

Hope that help you out.