# Paperclip missing.png not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In my member model I have a default url when no image is uploaded:

```
default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

in the assets/images folder I created a 'medium' folder and stored an image 'missing.png'

However, when I created a new member object and not upload an image, the webpage doesn't show the missing.png

Am I missing something?

I also tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665593/rails-paperclip-default-url-not-working/38666247#38666247) and changed the default setting to:

```
default_url: "/:style/missing.png"
```

but that didn't work.

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below working code. It's working fine in my case.

```
has_attached_file :content, styles: { thumb: "120x120>", medium: "160x226" }, default_url: "/assets/noimage/:style/missing.png",
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_protocol => 'https',
                    :s3_host_name => Settings.aws.s3.host_name,
                    :s3_credentials => {
                        :bucket => Settings.aws.s3.bucket,
                        :access_key_id => Settings.aws.access_key_id,
                        :secret_access_key => Settings.aws.secret_access_key
                    }
```

Comment: thanks, it's working with this setting: /assets/:style/missing.png